# Unexpected module 'PublicModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Angular4 Component Structure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to achieve a simple structure,

```
app
--_layout
  --public-footer
  ----public-footer.html/ts/css files
  --public-header
  ----public-header.html/ts/css files
  --public-layout
  ----public-layout.html/ts/css files
```

Inside public-layout.html:

```
<public-header></public-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<public-footer></public-footer>
```

Inside public-layout.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-public-layout',
  templateUrl: './public-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./public-layout.component.css']
})
export class PublicLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Now, this public-layout is to be used for other components like Home,About etc.

About things are not quite achieving for me, tried different combinations but none of them worked for me.

I am expecting that I should not declare/import header, footer in app.module.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: I deleted this entire layout and tried another combination. Now I think I am lost.

Comment: What is he current behavior of the layout and what is the desired one?

Comment: I am looking exactly as above, the requirement is very simple, need two layouts public and private and headers and footer will be different for of the layout and the above example is demonstrating public layout only. I am going to use this public layout component in Home/About

Comment: I have modified this at some extent in these hours. My question is very simple, if I like to use component in layout only, should I mention this in App.Module or where is the need to NgModules at diff. heirarchies

Comment: FYI, I am referring to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts. The only difference is I just don't want to include Header Footer Component in App.Module and that is where the problem started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here are two solutions for your case:

First is instead using the strategy with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your layout, you can use  and in each view where you desire your outlet you wrap the component.

```js
<app-app-layout>
  <h1>
  Html of some component that will be inside viewed inside the layout.
  </h1>
</app-app-layout>
```

With this strategy you can have as many layouts as you need.

The second solution is to use for the routing a tree based structure, for each layout for example from the app module you will have two branches.
One private with the desired outlet and inside of it you can place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` by doing so all of its children will have the outlet.
The second routing branch will be called public (for example) and this one will connect to all components/views which must not have an outlay.

I recommend the first strategy, here is a demo of the first solution based on your stackblitz   [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example-3sgftn?file=app%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.html)

Comment: Why you recommend the first one?

Comment: Because at some point you might need third and fourth layout , because of reasons  (Lets say for example the UI team just hate the dev team :D)  and at that moment it will be easier just to wrap the component in whatever layout is needed, other thing is that if you go with the second strategy, all your links will have a prefix `/private/...` or '/public/....' depending on the layout, which might not be the greatest user experience .